# Need to create bash script:

Tags: bash, docker, centos, docker-compose

-Autoinstall docker.

-Get 3 docker images(Apach,Nginx,MariaDB).

-Create `docker-compose.yml` file and configure it.

-Services should work: Apache:port 8080 Nginx:port 80 MariaDB:port 4000.

```
#!bin/bash
sudo yum -y update
sudo tee >/etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo <<-EOF
[dockerrepo]
name=Docker Repository
baseurl=https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg
EOF
sudo yum search docker-engine
sudo yum install -y docker-engine
sudo systemctl enable docker.service && systemctl start docker.service
sudo yum -y install epel-release
sudo yum -y install python-pip
sudo pip install docker-compose
sudo tee >/home/ash/docker_project/Dockerfile <<-EOF
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./public-html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs

FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EOF
cd /home/ash/docker_project
sudo tee >/home/ash/docker_project/docker-compose.yml <<-EOF
 version: '3' 

 services:
    apache: 
      image: httpd:2.4 
      ports: 
      - "8080:8080" 
      volumes: 
      - ./src:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs 

    web: 
      image: nginx
      volumes:
       - ./mysite.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template
      ports: 
       - "80:80" 

      command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

    db: 
      image: mariadb 
      ports: 
      - "4000:4000"
EOF
docker-compose up -d
```

Look like script is runs ok, there are no errors in terminal So my question is why I can not see start page of apache when I go on localhost:8080 the same with nginx and MariaDB?

All output is very long,but here is main stuff

```
Starting docker_project_apache_1 ... done
Starting docker_project_web_1    ... done
Starting docker_project_db_1     ... done
```

Also when I'm running `docker images` i see this list:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED
bitnami/apache      latest              569eec9f6f5c        4 days ago       
mariadb             latest              4828ff028cad        8 days ago
nginx               latest              ae513a47849c        4 weeks ago 
httpd               2.4                 fb2f3851a971        4 weeks ago
```

Comment: Have you started apache ?

Answer (score 1):

The `httpd` docker apache image exposes port 80, not 8080, see [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/) or [here](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/3af22f20b54cbb7c76ef4c3b12bd9dcf6cae862b/2.4/Dockerfile#L154).
Just change the line with apache ports in docker-compose:

```
  image: httpd:2.4 
  ports: 
  - "8080:8080"
```

to:

```
  image: httpd:2.4 
  ports: 
  - "8080:80"
```

and apache should be working.

@edit:

For mariadb container, it exposes port 3306.

As for nginx, you have bash error in your command line in docker-compose in web service. The bash command:

```
envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

will result in bash error, as /etc/nginx/conf.d is a directory. Probably you meant smth like:

```
envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.conf
```

Comment: Well, mariadb exposes port 3306, not 4000. Which leaves nginx, where you upload your custom configuration. Check if nginx has started with docker-compose logs.

Comment: about nginx logs has this output: "web_1   | /bin/bash: /etc/nginx/conf.d: Is a directory

Comment: Edited the answer ; )